# Lenovo Power Dial Software causing Errors

Tags: windows-7, event-log, lenovo-desktop-computer

I am using Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit Lenovo IdeaCentre K330. Recently i checked my Windows Event Viewer and i see that I have got a lot of the following error's:

#### SideBySide Event ID: 33

> Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program
>   Files\Lenovo\Power Dial\MFC80.DLL". Dependent assembly "Microsoft.VC80.MFCLOC,processorArchitecture="x86", publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b", type="win32", version="8.0.50608.0""
>   could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

---

This error occurs every time I boot my system. The Power Dial regulates the clock speed of the CPU and GPU in the system and it is provided by Lenovo. It is located in  `C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Power Dial` where also MFC80.DLL is located. They service's **LenovoCOMService** is on automatic.

Has someone experiences the same problem or has an idea how to solve this ? I don't want to delete the software or disable the services. I was actually searching on [Lenovo site](http://lenovo.com/us/en/#ss) for the Power Dial software to re-download it, but i could not find any link for download. If someone knows where i can re-download the software that would probably solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: Here is a link for power dial from software informer. I do not have a Lenovo to test it on, so this is just a suggestion that may be what you are looking for  http://power-dial.software.informer.com/

Comment: Also you may try to install the required package https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14431

Comment: @CarlB there is no link available at software informer.

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo why should i install Microsoft Visual c++ ?

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo it seems that downloading Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package solved the problem. Post your comment as answer and i will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14431) (found it by searching for the public key token)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @MartheenCahyaPaulo above the problem occurs because of the missing ***Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package***. To solve the problem just go [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14431) and download the Redistribution Package. After that you want see anymore the above mentioned error's in the Windows Event Viewer.